# Detect PRs with "Review required" in GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api

Using the GitHub API, I can't seem to detect if a pull request is in "Review required" status (as setup from https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/enabling-required-reviews-for-pull-requests).

It's not listed in the PR description in `https://api.github.com/repos/my_company/my_project/pulls` and the status list from `https://api.github.com/repos/my_company/my_project/statuses/abc123` only shows TravisCI statuses.

Since no review has happened, the comments from `https://api.github.com/repos/my_company/my_project/pulls/123/comments` are also empty (as expected, I just checked it to see if it also had review status).

So, is there an API call I'm missing that'll clearly indicate if a PR is in "Review required" status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nov. 2016: No there does not seem to be a direct API.

You can see all the future API evolution in [API Previews](https://developer.github.com/v3/previews/), and again there is nothing regarding reviews.
That would be a feature request for GitHub support.

Update January 2017, as mentioned by the [OP celadonz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843467/celadonz) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566997/detect-prs-with-review-required-in-github-api/40572475?noredirect=1#comment70356794_40572475), [listing reviews on PR is in beta](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/).

2020: Since then, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566997/detect-prs-with-review-required-in-github-api/40572475#comment112579483_40572475) by [Benjamin W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w), the official documentation is [`rest/reference/pulls#reviews`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#reviews), and it is indeed out of beta.

Comment: Sad but true. It is on the roadmap for https://developer.github.com/early-access/platform-roadmap/

Comment: The PR stuff is now in beta: https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/

Comment: @celadonz Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: It's now out of beta :)

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer and updated the documentation URL.